# duvida com senhas

Tags: angularjs, senhas

estou criando uma aplicação usando MVC. No lado servidor, estou usando c#/Asp.net MVC, no lado cliente estou usando html/angular.

No servidor tenho um metodo chamado Autenticar, que recebe o email e a senha, para buscar na base e verificar se o usuario esta cadastrado, funciona perfeitamente.

No lado cliente tenho esse metodo que chama o metodo Autenticar do server, passo o email e a senha:

```
$scope.pessoa = {};

        $scope.getPessoa = function (pemai, psenha) {
            var url = "http://localhost:23714/Pessoa/getBydesc?json=" + pemai;
            $http.get(url, pemai)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.pessoa = data;
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    alert("Erro");
                });

        };
```

Minha duvida é, como passar essa senha criptografada? qual a maneira mais adequada e segura para lidar com a senha nesse meu cenário?

Comment: Uma dica MVC não é uma tecnologia e sim uma maneira de "organizar o projeto". Sobre a senha acho que a unica que seria exposta seria de quem tenta autenticar e se a maquina ou rede "estiver contaminada", mas isso não expõe outros usuários. Todavia o SSL talvez pudesse ajudar, não vou responder ainda porque não sei se é o melhor caminho. O que achei estranho é que você só está enviando o email (login) mas não esta enviando a senha.

Comment: coloquei o codigo desatualizado ali, no meu codigo atual a senha vai tb.

Comment: Não adianta muito o front-end enviar a senha de maneira "criptografada" porque seria como enviar uma senha normal, entende? "Qualquer um" pode capturar a maneira criptografada e enviar assim mesmo que irá autenticar, o melhor talvez seria o SSL e uma pré sessão com token. Mas é muito amplo falar disso, não tenho conhecimento de C# com web pra fornecer um exemplo de como gerar o token.